# When exiting an org-src block, it always marks the buffer as edited

Tags: org-mode

When I'm editing source code contained in an org file, I use <kbd>C-c '</kbd> to call `#'org-edit-special`, which [opens up a new buffer](http://orgmode.org/manual/Editing-source-code.html) to edit that block in.

In this block, I'll often save (with <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd>), which will both move the changes to the original org file, and save that file. At this point, the org file is not marked as edited.

But when I exit that new buffer (<kbd>C-c '</kbd> again), the original org buffer is marked as edited, even though I saved it right before exiting the org-edit-special buffer. How can I make it not do this?

Comment: FWIW I cannot reproduce that with org 9.0

Comment: Interesting. I'm using 8.2.10.

Comment: After you save, what happens if you do `C-c C-k` instead of `C-c '`?

Comment: The original buffer is not marked as edited.

Comment: Is using `C-x C-s` and then `C-c C-k` an acceptable workaround?